# mysql - query to fetch most popular items which haven't been seen by user

Tags: mysql

Getting the most popular items is relatively easy. But let us say I have a table with two columns: `item_id` and `viewer_id`.

Given a `viewer_id`, I want to fetch the top X item_id rows which have been viewed the MOST times AND have not been viewed by the given `viewer_id`. So for example:

```
item_id | viewer_id
   A    |    1
   A    |    3
   C    |    2
   C    |    3
   C    |    4
   D    |    5
```

Getting most popular items not seen by viewer 2 should give back A, D.

What is a good way to go about this?

Comment: How many rows do you expect to have in this table? A straight query might not be the best way to go. Having an idea of the size of the problem would help. For a small website, a straight forward query should work fine. For a larger site, ...

Comment: Hey dhruvg, remember if your question has been answered, then you should select an answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should work:

```
SELECT t.item_id, COUNT(t.viewer_id) AS view_count FROM table t 
WHERE t.item_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM table t2 WHERE viewer_id = your_viewer_id)
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY view_count DESC
```

Comment: It looks like your filter is in the wrong place. The inner query should only include item_ids that this user has already viewed, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select item_id, count(*) as timesViewed from t2
where item_id not in (
    select distinct t1.item_id from t1
    where viewer_id = 2
)
group by item_id
order by timesViewed desc
```

Working [example](http://sqlize.com/sDltmIXfCh)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you don't just want them listed but ordered from most to least popular; this should work.

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM table_name a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT viewer_id FROM table_name t 
    WHERE a.item_id=t.item_id AND t.viewer_id=2
)
GROUP BY item_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(item_id) DESC;
```